# Unity 2D - Program Causing Insane Lag (String Code)

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, lag

So I am here mainly today to ask a question about some code that is causing insane lag. Firstly I will talk about the desired product. I was attempting to create a line of code that took a string and displayed 71 characters per line in a text object. Currently, it works perfectly fine, but Unity takes 4 minutes to actually play the code. It sits at this:

[image: Unity]

And it sits there for about 4 minutes before anything happens. During this time Unity acts frozen.
Here is the code:

`panelContainer` is just a scriptable `object` that holds details for different scriptable objects. The one this one uses is `TextPanels` which contain a Text variable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < panelContainer.textPanels.Length; i++)
    {
        GameObject batman = Instantiate(TextPrefab, this.transform);
        string buildAString = panelContainer.textPanels[i].Text;
        string temp = "";
        int index = buildAString.Length / 71;
        Debug.Log(index);
        for (int j = 0; j <= index; j++)
        {
            index++;
            if (buildAString.Length < 71) { temp += buildAString; buildAString = ""; }
            else { temp += buildAString.Substring(0, 71); temp += "\n"; buildAString = buildAString.Remove(0, 71); }
        }
        batman.GetComponent<Text>().text = temp;
    }
```

Comment: Consider using a StringBuilder. Your logic also doesn't make sense to me. You decide how many lines you need and store it in index, but then you increase index in every iteration. I suspect your loop runs for many more iterations than it should because of that. Consider stepping through in a debugger.

Comment: Ohh crap, I did not notice I was incrementing index still o.o
Also I will look into string builder, thanks for the tip on that.
Sometimes I wonder how blind I am >.>

Comment: @Retired Ninja feel free to submit that as the answer since it was the actual reason.